# static const array of static const arrays of doubles

Tags: c++, arrays

I managed to make an array of arrays of `double`s, having all of these `static` and `const`:

```
# myclass.h
class myclass {
    static constexpr double I_1[] = {... , ... , ... ...};
    static constexpr double I_2[] = {... , ... , ... ...};
    static constexpr double I_3[] = {... , ... , ... ...};
    ...

    static constexpr const double* list[] = {I_1,I_2,I_3,...};
}
```

Note that all arrays can have different sizes.

Now, this technique requires the definition of these static variables in the `cpp` file:

```
# myclass.cpp
constexpr const double* myclass::list[];
constexpr double myclass::I_1[], myclass::I_2[], myclass::I_3[],...
```

and this list can be very long if there are many arrays. This seems a little bit complicated to me.

**Is there a better way?**

Bonus question: **is there a way to do it without requiring C++11?**

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would recommend using a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. The most attractive aspect of `std::vector`, at least for me, is the ability to query for the size at run time.

Comment: @nathan I need some sort of database really, without reading an external file at runtime and without resource file for the compiler.

Comment: @Sahu, do vector allow static const?

Comment: @fffred Then I would suggest you still use a std::vector.  You would still need C++11 but as you are using that already it shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: @Nathan I understand your point, but I am not the only one using the code and if there is another way without C++11, it would be interesting. It is really the only place where C++11 would be required. Otherwise, then vector it is.

Comment: `std::vector` dates back to the 1990's, fffred. `constexpr`, now *that* is from 2011.

Comment: Do you need to prefill the "database" or do you generate the content on the run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide what I believe OP is looking for.

In a header somewhere and no C++11 required

```
class ConfigDB
{
public:
    static const std::vector<std::vector<double>> db;

};
```

The cpp file allocating ConfigDB::db requires c++11 for the nifty initializer list.

```
const std::vector<std::vector<double>> ConfigDB::db
{
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7}
};
```

Non C++11 alternatives include loading all of the `vector<double>`s and then loading those into the `vector<vector<double>>`. As bad or Worse than OP's solution with the arrays.

Comment: This seems better than my solution with arrays for sure. I guess I have to ensure users have C++11.

Comment: You should be able to pre-build the database-containing cpp file with C++11 and package it in a library for users without C++11 support. That's assuming the users don't have to modify the database.